# How to call a function inside a Firebase auth function?

Tags: javascript, function, firebase, nested, call

I have a function one and a Firebase authstatechange function inside it but I can't reach the function two outside.
the code:

```
function one() {

    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
        //code here

        function two() {
            //code here
        }
    });
}
// how to call function two here?
```

Comment: Put the function two outside and call it from the inside?

Comment: It would be better to place the function two inside the firebase auth function :(

Comment: Why? Do you need to access values from the callback?

Comment: Seems like you try to do the impossible...

Comment: I would like only one firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged and the function two only work with this.

Comment: It really seems impossible :(

Answer (score 2):

Define your `function two()` outside and call it from inside the `onAuthStateChanged` callback

```
function two() {
   //code here
}

function one() {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
        //code here
        two()
    });
}
```

Comment: But how to call it? Function one and the firebase function has several other functions and I would like the function two called only.